# Mysql multiple tables query searching same ID

Tags: mysql

[image]I have a problem regarding managing some database users and i need to have a query who envolves at least 4 tables and to count how many times this user id is present.

So i have activity, visit, class and pairs tables, and each user can insert a new record in each one.

Before having the possibility to delete an user, i must check in one query if his ID is present on each table...

How can achieve that?

Thanks

```
total_activity    total_visit      total_class     total_pairs
    3                   6               2              6
```

Comment: Start by showing us the schema for these 4 tables please, we are not clairvoyant

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using sub queries. This might help you.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activity_table_name WHERE someCondition) as total_activity, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit_table_name WHERE someCondition) as total_visit,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class_table_name WHERE someCondition) as total_class
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pairs_table_name WHERE someCondition) as total_pairs
```